# Is an AngularJS Controller a function or a class?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-controller

According to the AngularJS ng-controller documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController, ng-controller "attaches a controller class to the view". According to the AngularJS Controllers documentation: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller, it says: "When a Controller is attached to the DOM via the ng-controller directive, Angular will instantiate a new Controller object"

From what I read above, the controller is a class.

In the book "AngularJS Up and Running O'Reily" (which is a highly recommended book for learning AngularJS), on page 17, it says: "Controllers in AngularJS are our workhorse, the JavaScript FUNCTIONS that perform or trigger the majority of our UI-oriented work."

From my understanding, AngularJS Controllers are classes, not functions. How come the book refers to them here as JavaScript functions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Javascript doesn't have Classes, since it uses [prototype-based inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain). [ES6 Classes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes) are just functions that can be used with the `new` operator to initialize new objects to their prototype.

Comment: Correction: functions don't just return objects (that would be a factory), these are constructor functions which are instantiated with `new`.